# Using Cassandra PDO Driver on Windows

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

Is there any way to have Cassandra PDO at Windows with Wamp?

This is for development purposes I don't want to install Linux and change all the environment.

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/

I'm using Windows 7 (64 Bit), Wamp 2.5, PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I found out:

1) It's totally possible
2) The docs that appear in the first google search results are a bit obsolete

Start by downloading the latest Datastax Community Cassandra here:

http://planetcassandra.org/cassandra/

Install & setup properly. In fact, most of the configuration is done by the installer, you just have to edit the apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml file to find all paths to /var/lib... and change those into something like d:/cassandra/... That includes "commitlog", "data", "saved_caches". Restart the Cassandra service, examine the logs. Mine shown no problem. The OpsCenter at ...:8888/opscenter/index.html was working fine, showing one node online.

Now, the PHP part.

There's a sneaky thing called Thrift. From what I've learned today (I first heard about Cassandra and Thrift yesterday), it's a way describe a binary protocol of connecting to some online service, in this case, to Cassandra. It will basically generate PHP files that will provide all the connectivity you need from PHP itself (no extensions needed).

You will need:

1) The Thrift PHP libs
2) The .exe Thrift compiler

Both can be downloaded here:

https://thrift.apache.org/download

Then use the following command to compile PHP files that will act as a "driver" to connect your PHP applications to Cassandra:

thrift --gen php D:\DataStaxCommunity\apache-cassandra\interface\cassandra.thrift

Put the result in some PHP include_path folder.

Also, find the PHP Thrift libs (in the libs archive from the same download page) and put those in a folder accessible to your script (e.g. include_path or the project folder).

Refer this page:
thrift.apache.org/lib/php

I guess that should help!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Sorry, Jef, that was my first time on stackoverflow, I didn't pay attention that there are comments in addition to answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem as you, but when i tried this method, it works correctly for me. 
[Reference link](http://blog.carlesmateo.com/2014/07/31/begin-developing-with-cassandra/)

Here is a code example, very easy to understand :

```
<?php

require_once 'Cassandra/Cassandra.php';

$o_cassandra = new Cassandra();

$s_server_host     = '127.0.0.1';    // Localhost
$i_server_port     = 9042; 
$s_server_username = '';  // We don't use username
$s_server_password = '';  // We don't use password
$s_server_keyspace = 'cassandra_tests';

$o_cassandra->connect($s_server_host, $s_server_username, $s_server_password, $s_server_keyspace, $i_server_port);

$s_cql = "CREATE TABLE carles_test_table (s_thekey text, s_column1 text, s_column2 text,PRIMARY KEY (s_thekey));";

$st_results = $o_cassandra->query($s_cql);
```